# NodeJS i18n express change language with parameter (url)

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, i18next

I'm trying to translate my nodeJS+express+ejs website. I want my URL to have a language parameter. For the moment I have :

**[www.mywebsite.com?lang=en](http://www.mywebsite.com?lang=en)**

With :

```
i18n.configure({
    locales: ['en', 'fr'],
    directory: ('./locales'),
    queryParameter: 'lang'
})

app.use(i18n.init)

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.getLocale(),
        next();
});
```

It's working great, the query parameter change every page I have without changing code on my "app.get". But now I want my URL like this :

**[www.mywebsite.com/en/](http://www.mywebsite.com/en/)**

So I have this to setup language inside URL :

```
app.get('/:locale/', function (req, res) {
    localeTag = req.params.locale;
// code here
```

I tried :

```
app.use(i18n.init)

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  
    console.log(localeTag), // = "fr" or "en" it's working great.
    i18n.setLocale(localeTag),
        next();
});
```

But nothing works I'm still in english ? How can I apply my "localeTag" variable to i18n ? Documentation is poor...

Comment: setLocale() is getting executed for that specific scope or method and not globally.

Comment: you have an i18next tag, but your code does not look like to be i18next: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-middleware#wire-up-i18next-to-request-object